# React, get state without referencing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

```
let a = this.state.a; 
//setted in the constructor: {number: 1}

console.log(a); 
//Prints: {number: 1}

a.number = 2;
console.log(this.state.a);
//Prints: {number: 2}
```

How can I prevent `a` to be a reference, I want to change de value of `a` whitout changing the value of `state.a`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spread operator to create a new object:

```
let a = { ...this.state.a };
```

Alternatively, you can use `Object.assign`:

```
let a = Object.assign({}, this.state.a);
```

Comment: `let a = { ...this.state.a };` didn't work, but `let a = Object.assign({}, this.state.a);` works perfectly, thank you

Comment: To make the first option work, you'll have to [install the object rest spread transform babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/#installation).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new object based on the state object ...

```
let a = { ...this.state.a };
```

once you create a new object the reference will be gone..

We are using the spread operator to clone an object refer to this [article](http://2ality.com/2016/10/rest-spread-properties.html)..

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.assign`  like `let a = Object.assign({}, this.state.a, {number:2});`

or `Object Spread` like `let a = {...this.state.a};`